# all areas latitude and longitude between route defined

Tags: android

I am working on google map app.when i define a route For example from city one to city two ..then how can i get the latitude and longitude of all places coming between city one and city two.

```
    destinationid= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.destinationid);
    String clocation = destinationid.getText().toString();
    List<Address> addressList=null;
    if(clocation!= null || clocation!="")
    {
        Geocoder geocoder=new Geocoder(this);
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+clocation+""));
            startActivity(intent);

            addressList= geocoder.getFromLocationName(clocation,1);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Address address= addressList.get(0);
        LatLng latLng=new LatLng(address.getLatitude(),address.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Current Location  "));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Current Location  "));

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15.0f));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);  CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(latLng)
                .zoom(15)
                .bearing(150)
                .tilt(70)
                .build();

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);


    }'
```

Comment: why do you want list of latitude and longitudes?

Comment: Actually i am making final year university project. that is bus system application in which when driver moves from location A to location C  then i want notification when in between stop come like location B and secondly when i am near to location c almost radius of 25 meter i want to check if any student is available in that near by surrounding ...So if u can help me i will be greatfull

Comment: please add this above description in your question, and find my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question in comment above,
1] to show any particular point B on your route you can use `markers`, this is a feature of google maps API, more details about this you can find [here.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)

2] to check anyone is in your radius you can use `Geo fence` API. you can find more details [here.](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing)

Comment: Actually marker is use to locate the location on the map where as i want that when i reach at location b it should generate notification to the driver and to the students as well ....i am not professional still i am new at this to understand geo fence ..if u can guide more ..